# How to compare 2 tables and use the data that were similar in 1 table to return a column

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 2 tables, they both have Employee IDs, but only 1 of the table has Tracking numbers.
I basically wanna see where the same ID matched up and return the tracking numbers of those IDs that was present in both tables.

i already selected the columns I needed, and from which tables. I just can't return the tracking #.

```
SELECT a.[Employee ID], a.[Tracking #], b.[EMPLOYEE ID]
FROM [First_Table]a
LEFT JOIN [Second_Table]b
ON b.[EMPLOYEE ID] = a.[Employee ID]
WHERE b.[EMPLOYEE ID] IN 
    (SELECT a.[Tracking #]
    FROM [First_Table]a)
```

I expect the tracking number to spit back as something like "HTB1235"

Comment: Clean up your code, remove the `**`

Comment: Regarding your query, why would you need a sub-query in your WHERE when you are doing a JOIN?

Comment: The ** was just included in this question. Itt isn't actually in the code. Regarding the WHERE statement, that is where I got stuck. I'm not sure if that is necessary but I just want to obtain the tracking # from table A where the ID matched with table B's ID.

Comment: I get it that it was added here and I want you to remove it for better readability. To further improve your question and increase your chances of getting help include some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.Tracking
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.Employee = b.Employee
```

Comment: i just tried that and it gave me an error
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SCHORTS598' to data type int."

Comment: it seems that the Employee ID in the two tables are not the same Field Type. Can you please add sample data of the two tables to your question. This would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the traking # once regardless how many times the EmployeeID appears in the second table, use exists

```
SELECT a.[Tracking #]
FROM [First_Table] a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Second_Table WHERE EmployeeID = CAST(a.EmployeeID as VARCHAR))
```

Comment: i just tried that and it gave me an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SCHORTS598' to data type int."

Comment: Then, your tables have a column with the same name but different type, you need to post table definitions and sample data

Comment: @Anastasia One of your tables have EmployeeID INT and the other one is VARCHAR(N), how do you expect to match them?? SCHORTS598 = 598 or you have mixed value types in that column?

Comment: I have mix value types in that column

Comment: then cast the int column as varchar, is not the best idea to have it that way but is a workaround if you can't change it